# If ABC is a right triangle with right angle at C, and if BD is any line cutting AC at point D, prove that $BD^2+AC^2=AB^2+DC^2$

Tags: geometry

I was considering using the Pythagorean theorem to start the proof but I have no idea where to take it or if that would even work. If anyone has any helpful advice that would be greatly appreciated.

Also does MathJax Latex work in the title? I thought all I needed for superscript was the corresponding symbol but that doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Using Pythagoras in triangle  $ABC$,

$AC^2 + BC^2 = AB^2$

Now using Pythagoras in triangle $DBC$

$DC^2 + BC^2 = BD^2$

From the above equations, $AB^2 - AC^2 = BD^2 - DC^2$

or $\boxed{BD^2 + AC^2 = AB^2+DC^2}$

Answer (score 3):

DBC is also a right triangle with a right angle at C so from the Pythagorean Theorem:

$$DB^{2} = CD^{2} + CB^{2}$$

$$AB^{2} = CA^{2} + CB^{2}$$

So,

$$ DB^{2} + CA^{2} = (CD^{2} + CB^{2}) + (AB^{2} - CB^{2}) = CD^{2} + AB^{2} $$